# Hadoop: Installing Native Libraries on OS-X

Tags: macos, hadoop

Getting started with Hadoop and trying to install it on my machine. After installing it using brew, I can not run it's native commands like `hadoop fs -ls`.
 Hadoop Version: 2.6.0

OS: OS X Yosemite

Comment: Can you please provide more details? Do you get any error messages when trying to run those commands? It's hard to say what is wrong without more info...

Answer (score 0):

You should run the command like:

`hadoop fs -ls /`

This actually points to the root folder in HDFS and shows the files in there.

Like:
`Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2016-06-19 00:53 /user`

Try this.